# Make Laravel 5 registration a task for existing users

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, controller, registration

I'd like to reconfigure the default Laravel registration method so that only an existing user can register new users. However, I'm not sure how to reconfigure my AuthController so that the getRegister function does not automatically redirect to /Home when a user is already logged in.

Ideally, a user should be able to log in, hit a "Register New User" link, and then use the usual register user form. When completed, it should insert the new user credentials but then redirect them to their home page without changing their user session status at all.

It seems like it should just be an extra line or two in the Auth controller to disable the registration method's redirects, but I can't seem to figure it out from the Laravel docs. Can anyone help me out?

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

        public function getRegister() {
            $this->middleware('auth');
            parent::getRegister();
        }

        public function postRegister() {
            return redirect('/');
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>All you need to do is add a property to your `AuthController`.</strike>

```
protected $redirectPath = '/wherever/you/need/to/go';
```

That should take care of.  There are also other properties you can set to handle the internal auth system as well which are described in the docs.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

I think you can change the following to also exclude the register methods..

```
$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
```

Then the only issue is when your users register, they will automatically be logged in as that user.  One way I can think of to get around that which may be considered a little hacky is to save the user currently logged in in the constructor of `AuthController`

```
/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getLogout', 'getRegister', 'postRegister']]);
    $this->user = Auth::check() ?  Auth::user() : null;
}
```

Then you can add a destructor which will check that variable and if it's there, log your user back in as himself.

```
/**
 * Logs the user back in as himself in the event he has registered a new user.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __destruct()
{
    if(!is_null($this->user)) {
        Auth::login($this->user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure it answers my question - what I'm trying to do is have a user who is *already* logged in register *another* user, which is currently impossible since if you try to access the register method while logged in it just redirects you to home. Won't this just change the redirect destination for the regular registration process?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood.  I believe what you actually want to do then is comment out the line in `AuthController::__construct()` which adds the middleware for guest.  Make sure to save the currently logged in user though so you can re-login as them.

Comment: Hey, a hack is better than nothing at all. Thanks!